# Complex conjugate roots of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, contest-math

Consider the following polynomial equation with
$q_4, q_3, q_2, q_1$
, and $q_0$
real constants:

$$q_4z^4 + iq_3z^3 + q_2z^2 + iq_1z + q_0 = 0$$

If
$z = a + bi$
is a solution to this equation, where
a
and
b
are real constants and
$i^2 = -1$
, which of the following must also be a solution?

$(\text{A}) 
-a-bi$
$(\text{B})
a-bi
$
$(\text{C})
-a+bi
$
$(\text{D})
b+ai
$
$(\text{E}) \text{None of these}$

I chose B (I thought this was the obvious answer because of conjugates). However, it's C. Does the $i$ in front of $q_3$ and $q_1$ affect the answer? I noticed that in B, it has the $bi$ negated, and in C, the $a$ is negated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the change of variable $t=iz$. The given equation can be written as
$$q_4t^4-q_3t^3-q_2t^2+q_1t+q_0=0,$$
in which case we can apply the standard result that roots of polynomials with **real** coefficients appear as conjugate pairs. So if $t_1=-b+ai$ is a solution, then $t_2=-b-ai$ is also a solution. But, in terms of $z$, these solutions are $z_1=a+bi$ and $z_2=-a+bi,$ as the answer provides.